# Heroku ActionView::Template::Error eof (undefined) in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I deployed my app to Heroku.
I am having this error in the log :

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected token: eof (undefined)
(in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)):
:     3: <head>
:     4:   <title>wkkin</title>
:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
: GET xxx.herokuapp.com/users/2/edit dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1
292ms status=500 bytes=728
:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
:     8: </head>
:     9: <body>
:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1096119453842232088_43006600'
```

My application.js looks like :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

I have three files in my folder app/assets/javascripts/

- application.js
- form.js
- users.js.coffee

in application.rb : config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
in production.rb : config.assets.compile = true

Any idea ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This often means you have a missing closing `}` in one of your .js files not just application.js. I would check that.

Comment: Thanks Yuri for the hint. You were right !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This often means you have a missing closing } in one of your .js files not just application.js. I would check that.